# Bootstrap v4 not working (Spring, Thymeleaf, Java8)

Tags: java, html, spring, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

When switching from bootstrap v3.3.7 to v4, a problem occurs. The page is loaded without any styles. I tried to add in many ways:

1. CDN urls (working but its not exit for me).
2. Locally. Adding css/js files in static folder.
3. With Maven dependency.

But nothing comes out.
It is interesting that my main.css is working and also is in static folder.

What could be the problem?

I use:

Java 8

Thymeleaf

Spring

Maven

[header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j78a.png)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
   xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<head>
 <!-- Font Awesome -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/static/css/main.css}"/>
</head>
```

[folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wcgma.png)

[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xoRi.png)

Comment: Please post text when you're posting code, not images. The path to the `min.css` file doesn't match what you show in your file tree.

Comment: But if the compiler recognizes .css file and I can go to it from the link in href, it's not enough?

Comment: Can you post your project directory structure and your pom.xml file? WebJars need to go in a specific directory under resources and need the dependency in the pom.xml file.

Comment: Re:  "CDN urls (working but its not exit for me)".  What do you mean by "exit"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem always occur because if you are not giving the bootstrap a proper path. Kindly see the path to reach bootstrap and then try again. The only problem seems to to be is the path provided.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the path is correct. I can go to .css files by clicking on the link in href. I changed header image to more relevant.

Comment: @EricShooter The path in your file tree shows `min` *under* a poorly-named directory. Plus if you have it as a static resource then you should access it as a static resource as the file that *does* work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the configuration which worked for me

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf:2.1.5.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.webjars:bootstrap:4.0.0-2'
    implementation 'org.webjars:webjars-locator:0.30'
    implementation 'org.webjars:font-awesome:5.11.2'
}
```

your.html

CSS

```
    <link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/4.0.0-2/css/bootstrap.min.css} "/>
    <link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css} "/>
```

javascript

```
<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/popper.js/umd/popper.min.js}"></script>
<script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
```

Additionally if you have `WebMvcConfigurer` implemented, you need to add the resource handler accordingly

```
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/", "/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/", "/assets/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("/", "/webjars/");
    }
```